# Issues with regions using the Spaces Dashboard module

Tags: features, 7

I have been facing many issues trying to use the Spaces Dashboard module (part of the [Spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces) module).

I have setup a site with pressflow, OG, Context, Spaces, and Features; I got everything working well together.

I have been trying to implement the Spaces Dashboard feature, so group managers can manage their own group front page with an easy to use drag'n drop UI.

- Through context, I have been able to create a default dashboard with some enabled blocks.
- I have configured all spaces_dashboard settings and saved them in my default group space so every new group is shipped with those settings.
- I have done some workaround in my template to get the context working with my **Zen subtheme** (based on #26 at http://drupal.org/node/633778).
- I can now drag and drop blocks from my dashboard edition block to my theme regions.
- I followed this tuto for setting up the UI (not really fully working with zen subtheme) : http://www.leveltendesign.com/answer/adding-customize-dashboard-magic-your-drupal-theme
- I can currently drop blocks in ANY of the theme's regions even the disabled ones. I'm not sure of where does the problem comes from. The region settings are setup in the module config page at both site level and spaces level.
- I cannot drop blocks in empty regions. ("Empty" meaning any region on the page that does not contains any block yet.)
- If I move a block out of a region and there is no block anymore in the region I cannot move it back in the region. I'm not sure if this is a CSS, JS or module issue.
- I found that by adding div for empty regions I can get some empty regions to work, but this is just a html trick and not a solution. `<div class="region region-content-top"><div class="section ui-sortable"><a class="context-block-region" id="context-block-region-content_top">Content top</a></div></div>`
- Finally, the 'save' button from the dashboard block doesn't save any modification to the dashboard in the current space nor in the global settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone still cares about this ...

You cannot drop blocks into empty regions, because they are empty. You can tell the dashboard settings to show all regions always, and then use CSS to hide the regions you dont want to be droppable ever via display none in CSS i think. Thats what I did.

The save button issue you would have to debug with Firebug and maybe a php profiler. You need to be sure the zen theme has allllll the html and css needed by the Gingko theme as lined out in that blog post above for the various JS actions to get processed correctly for the dashboard editor.

I followed the same tutorial for a Zen subtheme, spaces, dashboard and spaces_node and got it all working -- migrating to D7 looks like a pain in the future.

Answer (score -4):

Please check the [Homebox](http://drupal.org/project/homebox) module. Homebox is also used on drupal.org to manage user profiles. Here is another good article about implementing dashboards: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/building-drupal-dashboard